# I am not able to save value in added custom field in customer address in magento 2

Tags: custom-attributes, customer-address, magento2.1.0

I have created the custom field in customer address section in magento admin and attribute created successfully and visible in customer admin area using below code:-

```
 <?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

   use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
    /**
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
    {
        /**
         * Customer setup factory
         *
         * @var CustomerSetupFactory
         */
        private $customerSetupFactory;
        /**
         * @var AttributeSetFactory
         */
        private $attributeSetFactory;
        /**
         * Init
         *
         * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
         */
        public function __construct(
            CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
            AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
        ) {
            $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
            $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
        }
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
         */
        public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
            /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $setup->startSetup();

            $kcaddressidInfo = [
                    'kc_address_id' => [
                    'label' => 'Custom address id',
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'position' => 1000,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => false,
                    'system' => 0,
                    'user_defined' => true,
                    'position' => 1000,
                ]
            ];
            $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer_address');
            $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
            /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
            $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
            $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

            foreach ($kcaddressidInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
                $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', $attributeCode, $attributeParams);
            }

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'kc_address_id');

            $attribute->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
            ]);

            $attribute->save();
            $setup->endSetup();
        }
    }
```

but after created the attribute I am not able to save value in this attribute.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Before asking question you should accept the previous answer to clean the community

Answer (score 1):

**Looks like you missed few parameters which is required to save its value like Global.**

**Try below code :**

```
/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $setup->startSetup();

        $kcaddressidInfo = [
                'kc_address_id' => [
                'label' => 'Custom address id',
                'type' => 'int',
                'input' => 'text',
                'backend' =>' ',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'position' => 1000,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'system' => 0,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'position' => 1000,
            ]
        ];
        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer_address');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        foreach ($kcaddressidInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
            $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', $attributeCode, $attributeParams);
        }

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'kc_address_id');

        $attribute->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
        ]);

        $attribute->save();
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
```

Comment: When I use your code it give me error: `Something went wrong while saving the customer.`